# What is the relation/difference between worst case time complexity of an algorithm and its upper bound?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, clrs

What is the relation/difference between worst case time complexity of an algorithm and its upper bound?

Comment: When you say "upper bound" you mean big-O?

Answer (score 3):

The term "upper bound" is not very clear, as it may refer to two possible things:

1. The upper bound of the algorithm - the bound where the algorithm can never run "slower" than it. This is basically the worst case performance of it, so if this is what you mean - the answer is pretty simple.
2. big-O notation, which provides an upper bound on the complexity of the algorithm under a specific analysis. The big-O notation is a *set of **functions***, and can be applied to any analysis of an algorithm, including worst case, average case, and even best case.

Let's take [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) as an example.

Quick Sort is said to have `O(n^2)` worst case performance, and `O(nlogn)` average case performance. How can one algorithm has two complexities? Simple, the function representing the analysis of average case, and the one representing the worst case, are completely different funcitons - and we can apply big O notation on each of them, there is  no restriction about it.

Moreover, we can even apply it to best-case. Consider a small optimization to quick-sort, where it first checks if the array is already sorted, and if it is - it stops immidiately. This is effectively `O(n)` operation, and there is some input that will provide this behavior - so we can now say that the algorithm's best case complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: @NiranjaniElango I leave option (1) for future readers then, but you really are interested in point 2 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between worst case and big O(UPPER BOUND) is that 
    **the worst case** is a case that actually happens to your code,
    **the upper bound** is an overestimate, an assumption that we put in order to 
    calculate the big O, it doesn't have to happen

*example on insertion sort:*

Worst Case:

The numbers are all arranged reversely so you need to arrange and move every single 
    number

Pseudo-code

```
for j=2 to n
  do key = a[i]
  i=j-1
  while i>0 & a[i]>key
    do a[i+1] = a[i]
    i=i-1
  end while
  a[i+1]=key
end for
```

Upper Bound:

We assume that the order of the inner loop is i =n-1 every single time, but in fact, 
    it is changeable every time, it can't be n-1 every time, but we assumed 
    /overestimated it to calculate the big O